# List View Quick Action

Tags: standard-objects, list-view, quickaction

I am in Lightning and I am trying to add a Quick Action to a List View for Opportunities. I only see the option of adding a Button. However, by custom objects I do see the option of adding a Quick Action.

I would appreciate it if anyone can shed light on this if this is a bug or by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's by design. As outlined in [Set Up Mass Quick Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mass_quick_actions_create.htm&type=5):

> Mass quick action lets your users edit up to 200 records in a list view. You can perform mass quick actions on create and update quick actions on cases, leads, and custom objects in Lightning Experience. To set up mass quick actions, you customize the object’s search layout.

So, for now, only Leads, Cases, and Custom Objects are supported. Future releases may include other objects, but when or what they are have not been listed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Salesforce says this is not Custom Quick Actions are not supported in Lightning.

"Except for the Tasks object, only standard button actions are supported on list view items. Items in Tasks list views contain the full list of actions available for tasks."

See: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think that you are referring to List View Record Level actions. I am referring to List Level actions. Sorry for not being clearer